# Optimize regular expression for filtering thousands of HTML select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, optimization, diacritics

## Background

I developed a jQuery-based [shuttle widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13557000/59087) for HTML `select` elements because I could not find one that was minimally codified and offered a regular expression filter that compensated for [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).

## Problem

When a few thousand entries are added to the `select`, the regular expression filter slows to a crawl. You can see the problem as follows:

1. Browse to: http://jsfiddle.net/U8Xre/2/
2. Click the input field in the result panel.
3. Type any regular expression (e.g., `^a.*ai`).

## Code

I believe the culprit is lurking here:

```
var options = $src.empty().scrollTop( 0 ).data( "options" );
var search = $.trim( $input.val() );
var regex = new RegExp( search, 'gi' );
var len = options.length;
var $html = $(document.createElement( 'option' ));
for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
  var o = options[ i ];
  if( o.text.dediacritics().match( regex ) !== null ) {
    $src.append( $html.clone().text( o.text ).val( o.value ) );
  }
}
$src.css( 'width', $input.width() + 4 );
```

Where `$src` is the source `$('#select')` and `String.prototype.dediacritics` is defined as in the fiddle. The code above runs for every single keypress. There is one more relevant snippet:

```
// Create a copy of the source options to use when matching the regex.
var $options = [];
$src.find( "option" ).each( function() {
  $options.push( { value: $(this).val(), text: $(this).text() } );
});
$src.data( "options", $options );
```

This makes a copy of the options from the source list, but only runs once. (This results in a duplication bug when shuttling options, but adding the above code into the `input` event handler would slow the filter even more.)

## Question

How can the code be made to perform regular expression filtering on lists up to 5,000 words in nearly real-time?

Thank you!

Comment: Just never add thousands of entries to a `<select>` element. Everything above 7 is not user-friendly, and everything above 20 needs a reasoned statement for justification.

Comment: This is for a maintenance screen used by a few people. Otherwise, they'd have to hand-categorize items directly in the database. I'm not looking for different UX solutions: everything works, albeit slowly.

Comment: My guess is it isn't the regex that's the bottleneck. Can you narrow the bottleneck down a bit more?

Comment: May I ask: Where did you find that fancy `dediacritics` function, is that maintained somewhere?

Comment: @Bergi: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5912746/59087 ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess the harder job is the repeated call to `dediacritics()` (with its many regex-replaces) than doing the search (though I haven't done any profiling). So, you should cache these de-diacriticified strings and search only through them. Btw, [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) is usually faster than `match`.

Also, you should avoid as many DOM operations as possible - you have a lot of them when emptying and re-appending the whole options list onkeypress.

```
// once:
var options = [],
    src = $src[0]; // or whatever to get the DOM element
$.each( src.options, function() {
    options.push( { el: this, text: $(this).text().dediacritics(), hidden:false } );
});
// you might put it on the element via .data(), but need not

// onkeypress:
var regex = new RegExp( $.trim($input.val()), 'i' );
var curEl = src.firstChild;
for (var i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
    var option = options[i];
    if (regex.test( option.text )) {
        if (option.hidden)
            src.insertBefore(option.el, curEl);
        curEl = option.el.nextSibling;
        option.hidden = false;
    } else {
        if (!option.hidden) {
            curEl = option.el.nextSibling;
            src.removeChild(option.el);
        }
        option.hidden = true;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8Xre/5/): This is blazingly fast ("realtime"), but you can feel the time it needs to construct the `options` array when calling `dediacritics()` 5000 times.

Comment: Very nice; might have to optimize this a bit more for fixing the shuttling bug. Looks super-fast.

Comment: Right, I've missed that. I'd recommend just another binary property to store in which list the `option` currently is, and just `continue` the for-loop then.

Comment: There is another bug: this will exclude every other item that matches the RegEx. If you had `Toy Box`, `Toy Story`, and `Toy Zebra`, then `^Toy` will not show `Toy Story` in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Cause of the problem was the `lastIndex` flag on the (unnecessary) *global* regex, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1520800/1048572. Fixed now.

Comment: @ridgerunner: Removing the `global` flag (as I did) does also work

Comment: @Bergi - quite right. (forgot about how the g flag affects this) I stand corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to

- create a multi-line string containing a list of all option names, each in a separate line
- apply regex to this multi-line string to filter its content by removing non-matching lines
- update html with matching lines as options of select element

Comment: I was thinking along those lines. The `$src.append` looks rather inefficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A minor comment, if you aren't using the result of the regex match, then you should use a regex test:

```
  if( o.text.dediacritics().match( regex ) !== null ) {
```

use a test:

```
  if( regex.test(o.text.dediacritics()) ) {
```

Comment: No, this answer is missing a crucial initialization and running it as-is will lead to erroneous behavior. Like `RegExp.exec()`, the `RegExp.test()` method uses the regexp instance object's `lastIndex` property to determine where to begin its search on any string and `test()` does _NOT_ reset this property after a successful match (it does reset it on match failure). Subsequent tests (on other strings) following a successful match will begin at a non-zero location - ERROR! To work correctly, this answer needs to add: `regex.lastIndex=0;` somewhere before: `regex.test()`.

Comment: Additionally, as @Bergi correctly points out, you could alternately build the regex with the global `g` flag off - which also forces the reset of: `RegExp.lastIndex` each time it is run.