# How can i improve performance of search script?

Tags: javascript, performance

I have UL list with many items and some input. My script listens to key up on input and show or hide field that match input string.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#srvSearchField').keyup(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();

        $('.srvClientBlock').each(function(){
            var currentFieldValue = $(this).children('.srvClientName').html();
            var exp = new RegExp(value);

            if (currentFieldValue.match(exp)) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can i improve performance? Or i should send request on my server to find matched values?

UPD:
I decided use ajax to filter clients.

```
var url = "<?php echo $searchClientUrl;?>";

$(function(){
    $('#srvSearchField').keyup(function(){
        var request = $(this).val();

        var callback = function(response) {
            $('.srvClientBlock').hide();

            var data = JSON.parse(response);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#srvClient-' + data[i]).show();
            }
        };

        $.post(url, {"request" : request}, callback);
    });
});
```

Thanks everyone for answers.

Comment: What exactly are the performance issues you're having? Is the regex slow, are there so many elements the page hangs while their states are toggled? It's difficult to tell from your question

Comment: Move `var exp` outside the `$.each` for one. It uses `value`, so you don't need to create a `new RegExp` each iteration. Just do it once per keyup

Comment: You want `.text()` instead of `.html()`, don't you? Nobody searches for HTMl entities :-)

Answer (score 5):

Some points:

- Don't recreate the regex for each searched list item.
- Use the `test` method of the regex instead of `match`.
- Cache the searched text (srvClientName) somewhere so you don't have to query the DOM so often.
- You even can cache it outside the DOM, so you only need to access it when you need to toggle a display (see [this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13557544/1048572)).
- If the DOM updates still take too long, consider a) hiding the complete UL during manipulations b) only show any results at all when their count is below a certain number

Of course, caching only applies if your list contents do not change dynamically (or at least you'd need to rebuild the cache every time).

Sending requests to the server for each search makes only sense under certain circumstances:

- limited (mobile) client resources that render storing and/or processing of huge data impossible
- limited bandwidth that forbids downloading the whole data
- live data on the server (that cannot be sent to the client continuously)

but they require enough bandwidth for many requests and a relatively small latency. You can target those problems with special optimizations, though.

```
// simple improvements, no caching:
$(function(){
    $('#srvSearchField').keyup(function(){
        var exp = new RegExp( $(this).val() );
        $('.srvClientBlock').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var currentFieldValue = $this.children('.srvClientName').text();
            $this[ exp.test(currentFieldValue) ? "show" : "hide" ]();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @NikitaMelnikov, Please note that this does not help if your search queries are very heavy despite these optimizations. You might want to limit the number of search calls you make by not reacting to EVERY single key press. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid ajax requests, do so. You might need to use them though if you are having client-side problems, the browser can handle only so much data.

If you need to work with ajax requests or a lot of data, set up your keydown event to start a 100-300 ms timeout that is reset and restarted on every subsequent keydown, which in turn calls your search function. That way your search will run only when the user is idle for 200ms (not much, but enough to cut down number of search calls by a lot).

Comment: The OP doesn't use Ajax at all?

Comment: @Bergi, The OP specifically asked if he should be doing server requests to optimize. Do you know other ways of doing server requests besides ajax?

Comment: Oops, I missed that he *considered* to contact the server. Unfortunately I can't remove the downvote until you edit the post :-/

Comment: @Bergi, Simply click the down arrow again to reset your vote. Failing that, refresh the page. You CAN recall votes.

Comment: "*You last voted on this answer [a too long time ago]. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited*" - of course I could edit it myself :-)